# How to add IDictionary<string,string> type from angular to webapi m ethod

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api2

I have an asp.net webapi with a parameter as `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,string>>`

I am calling this api method from my angular frontend with the following value:

`var x = "{'state':california'}"`

i have an array var y = []; Now i want to push x as an keyvalue object ie.

y.push({'state':'california'}).

Right now when i do y.push(x); it is adding as string ie. "`{'state':'california'}"`

Because it is adding as string the array, the parameter is null in the api method.

Can anyone please help me how to make this item as key/value object in that array?

Thanks

Comment: `var x= {state: 'california'}`

Comment: this is not set as hardcoded value. this is entered in a textbox.

Comment: `var x = JSON.parse("{state: 'california'}")`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

`y.push(JSON.parse('{"key": 'state', "value": 'california'}'));`

or something like this

```
var y= [];
y.push({ key: "state", value: "california" });
y.push({ key: "state", value: "other" });
```

Hope any one of this method will work - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

convert your string to a json object as

```
var x = '{"state":"california"}' 
y.push(JSON.parse(x))
```

Comment: getting unexpected token ' in json at position 1

Comment: your object should be like this '{"state":"california"}'

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help

Declare:

```
 let  keyval: { [id: string]: string; } = { "state": "california", "SVR": "Chan" };

 y.push(keyval)
```